# how to force a photo into black and white

Tags: android

So if the user takes a photo in color, I want to save it as a black and white picture.

Could someone help me?

Comment: i want store in Black and white mode when i take photo from camera..

Comment: Are you taking the photo programmatically?

Comment: Looks like you need some image post-processing after taken from the camera. So, Basically your question is how to convert color Bitmap to the grayscale and save it?

Answer (score 2):

you have to set camera parameter by
see [parameter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a rather crappy phone (I do - Xperia X8), then you won't be able to apply any color effects at all. To find out what color effects are supported by your phone, you could use something like this:

```
Camera.Parameters params = cam.getParameters();

try {           
    for (String e : params.getSupportedColorEffects()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Effect: " + e);
    }
}
catch (NullPointerException npe) {
    Log.d(TAG, "No color effects supported by this camera.");           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> `cameraParams.getSupportedColorEffect();` and check if it contains `Parameters.EFFECT_MONO` then set

```
cameraParams.setColorEffect(android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_MONO);

mCamera.setParameters(cameraParams);
```