# Black and white photo in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to force a photo into black and white](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348468/how-to-force-a-photo-into-black-and-white)

i want to store Black and white photo when  i take photo from mobile camera.

Comment: Don't ask the same question again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348468/how-to-force-a-photo-into-black-and-white

Answer (score 8):

Something like this should work:

```
public Bitmap greyScaler(Bitmap b) {    
     Bitmap grayscaleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(b.getWidth(),
            b.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
     Canvas c = new Canvas(grayscaleBitmap);
     Paint p = new Paint();
     ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
     cm.setSaturation(0);
     ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
     p.setColorFilter(filter);
     c.drawBitmap(b, 0, 0, p);
     return grayscaleBitmap;
}
```

Comment: If i want to Set the camera screen for the same effect then ??