# Image Manipulation in Android app

Tags: android, android-emulator, image-manipulation, android-2.2-froyo, android-image

Can anyone help me on this one?
I want to do image manipulation in my Android app like Brightness and Contrast. 
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I previously [posted an example of how to greyscale an image in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349397/black-and-white-photo-in-android/5350008#5350008). This code could be used as a starting point for basic image manipulation. I also suggest you check out the [ColorMatrix class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrix.html)