# Android Customizing Image and Saving

Tags: android, image, android-assets, customizing

How can I make an image customisable (size, colour, opacity, ...) like [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-generic.html) (in the app)? Then, save it as a custom name inside an external folder?

Comment: use gimp or photoshop or any other graphic tool

Comment: Are you saying you want to do this on the device, or are you asking how to add images to your application project?

Comment: On the device, not on the computer...

Answer (score 0):

Anything in the drawables folder (all resources, actually) has to be there at compile time, you can't add resources dynamically. If you want to edit images on the device, you'll have to save/load from one of the app's storage directories, ie it won't be available under R.

If you're asking how to add resources to your project, just edit them with any editing tool such as Photoshop and copy the file into one of the folders under src/main/res/drawable depending on size as described here (http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Edit: if you're asking how to do image editing in an application, there's no quick and easy way to do this. Most drawing solutions are built using a [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html). If all you want to do is choose between a limited selection of options like size and opacity, you might be better off just having the user make their selections from a list of values and generate the image when they're done.

Comment: I was actually asking how to make the user customise the image inside the app then save it in a data folder, then use the image for a service.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this, this might help.

[Image Manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962032/image-manipulation-in-android-app)

You can edit an image in the asset and save it in a different location.